# What Software Is Available For Creating Server-Side PDF Files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

I need a robust product for creating PDF files out of web pages on a web server using a C# API for ASP.NET WebForms/MVC. The product should support SVG and PATH tags in the markup as well as being able to render markup created via ajax calls that fire after the page is rendered. The following steps will give you a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish.

1. The user clicks an "Export To PDF" button on a webpage. This sends a request to a generic handler (an ashx file).
2. The generic handler validates the user's credentials and security clearance and then passes the URL of a webpage that is to be rendered as a PDF file to a PDF generation tool (this is where the C# API comes into play).
3. The PDF generation tool saves the PDF file in a temporary folder on the server.
4. The temporary PDF is read into a byte array and sent to the response stream where the user can then download the file.
5. If the PDF generation tool supports it, it will return the PDF file to the user's browser instead of saving to a temporary location on the server.

I'm currently using activePDF's WebGrabber tool to accomplish this, but it's having issues rendering Kendo DataViz charts (they use SVG and PATH tags). I've also tried Aspose.Pdf and it's horrendous. I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience with this and can recommend a professional tool that can handle these requirements.

Just some final notes:

- The WebBrowser.Print() method is not an option.
- Does Adobe offer anything for these requirements?
- I've looked at iText and I can't tell if it supports Kendo DataViz charts or not.

Comment: iTextSharp has always worked for me, though you may have to build a few of the simpler parts you seek (1,2,5)

Comment: Just as an FYI - these types of recommendation questions are not generally welcome on Stack Overflow.  See the [faq#close] section on close reasons, specifically "not constructive".

Comment: have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136217/html-to-pdf-or-image-c-sharp/15136335#15136335

Comment: possible duplicate of [Commercial HTML-to-PDF component for .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055838/commercial-html-to-pdf-component-for-net)

Comment: I totally disagree about this question not being constructive. I found it useful. IMHO SO's collective opinion on this sort of thing has become involuted and perverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had requirement to generate PDFs in server using our WCF service. Our need was to create PDFs and merge, we used PDFSharp,not sure if it can handle what you described.

http://www.pdfsharp.net/

We also used ActiveReports server version 7 which takes input as xml and gives output as PDF,WORD and HTML

Comment: PdfSharp apparently uses GDI+ or WPF, both of which are not safe to use in a server process (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [ActiveReports](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ActiveReports/) to generate PDFs, but this is more of a reporting engine that can export to PDF. If you could obtain the screenshot as an image, you could dynamically add an image to the report, and then send it to the PDF.

Alternately, if the requirement is to print a specific page, like a receipt, then I would not grab a URL. Instead, I would lay out the receipt as a report, and then supply the appropriate data to generate that report, export it as a PDF, and have it delivered to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I've rendered PDFs from web pages using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) in ASP.NET MVC before.  However, I've always called it as an exe, not from an API.

It looks like there is a project to provide a C# API for it [here](https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp).